# What happened to this bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

So I answered [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206294/programmatically-disable-menu-based-on-user-taxonomy-reference-fields/206332#206332) that a bounty on it. It was accepted before the end of the bounty period, however, it only granted me standard answer points. Once the grace period ended, it didn't award me the full or  1/2 bounty credit (which I presume because it was marked as answered).

So what happened here? Are awarding bounties & accepting an answer 2 distinct actions? I presumed they were the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get the bounty because you answered before the bounty was offered. [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) states:

> If the **bounty starter accepted an answer** during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty (**provided that the answer was posted during the bounty period**). Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense given that it's a tool to promote visibility. Thx.

Comment: To me, it would make sense to give the bounty to the accepted answer, even if it was answered earlier, but if that is the only answer.

Comment: I definitely _prefer_ it to be that way. My prior research (your linked question), seem to indicate everything about bounties is just for visibility. I guess that might make more sense on SO where there's much more post volume than on DA.